# Finding all transitions in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as such :

| Product | Day 0 Owner | Day 1 - reason | Day - 1 New Owner | Day - 2 reason | Day - 2 New Owner | Day - 3 reason | Day - 3 New Owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laptop | Mark |  |  | Webcam issue | Anna | Charge issue | David |
| Phone | Grorge | Signal issue | Joe | Charge issue | David |  |  |
| MP3 Player | Sam |  |  |  |  | Audio issue | Pam |
| Speaker | Ben |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Day 0 Owner basically shows who is currently working on a product on day 0 - the start of the month.
Everyday, there is a chance that the product might face a problem and current owner of the product might give the product to someone else to work on. This is denoted by **Day - # reason** (the issue with product) and **Day - New Owner** (Whom the product was given to, to work upon)
Some products might not have any transitions as well, example for the speaker in the above table.

What I am trying to find is a list / data frame of all transitions(including repetions, irrespective of the product), which would look something like this:

| From | Reason | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Webcam issue | Anna |
| Anna | Charge issue | David |
| Grorge | Signal issue | Joe |
| Joe | Charge issue | David |
| Sam | Audio issue | Pam |

Note that there is no entry for Ben, since there were no transitions.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

Even though a minimal working example would have been nice... here's how you could do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = "Product    Day 0 Owner     Day 1 - reason  Day - 1 New Owner   Day 2 - reason  Day - 2 New Owner   Day 3 - reason  Day - 3 New Owner\n\
Laptop  Mark            Webcam issue    Anna    Charge issue    David\n\
Phone   Grorge  Signal issue    Joe     Charge issue    David       \n\
MP3 Player  Sam                     Audio issue     Pam\n\
Speaker     Ben                         "

df = pd.DataFrame([map(str.strip, i.split("\t")) for i in s.split("\n")])
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
df = df.replace("", pd.NA)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------


changes = []
for i in range(1,4):
    key = f"Day - {i} New Owner"
    reasonkey = f"Day {i} - reason"
    
    where = ((df["Day 0 Owner"] != df[key]) & ~df[key].isna()) 
    change_df = df.loc[where][["Product", "Day 0 Owner", reasonkey, key]]
    change_df["day"] = f"Day {i}"
    
    changes += change_df.values.tolist()
    
changes = pd.DataFrame(changes).set_index(0)
changes.index.name = "Product"
changes.columns = ["From", "Reason", "To", "Day"]

print(changes)
```

```py
>>>              From        Reason     To    Day
>>> Product                                       
>>> Phone       Grorge  Signal issue    Joe  Day 1
>>> Laptop        Mark  Webcam issue   Anna  Day 2
>>> Phone       Grorge  Charge issue  David  Day 2
>>> Laptop        Mark  Charge issue  David  Day 3
>>> MP3 Player     Sam   Audio issue    Pam  Day 3
```